# How to fix/reset bluetooth on Lenovo Y50-70?

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

I have a Lenovo Y50-70 with Ubuntu 16.04 and Bluetooth problems.

Previously I had elementary OS installed and the Bluetooth worked fine.

It currently detects the Bluetooth adapter but does not allow me to change visibility of the system to be discoverable nor find any devices.

I tried running a live USB with Ubuntu and the Bluetooth worked just fine, it allowed me to change settings and discover devices, which makes me think there is something broken on my installation.

How can I reset the settings or fix this issue?

I'm hoping I can avoid a clean install.

This is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:b736]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
Kernel modules: rtl8723be
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 045e:07b2 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174f:14b8 Syntek 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 added the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`

Comment: `rtl8723be` is a combo chip, Wi-Fi+BT. WiFi is fixable, but BT is problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a problematic chipset. In Ubuntu 14.04 the BT device was not supported on Linux, but it was possible to install a custom `rtl8723au-bt` module. I even added to my PPA as a DKMS module. It used to work quite well.

Now the code has been merged into the Linux tree, and the device is supposed to be supported. But many people complain that it actually does not work well enough.

The old DKMS module does not work on new kernels.

I do not have this hardware, that's why I do not have a chance to investigate this problem and suggest a solution.

I can suggest to search the net by "linux rtl8723be bluetooth". Maybe someone has fixed it some way or another. Also I would recommend to create a bug report at Launchpad if it does not exist.

It may also be useful to contact the kernel maintainers, but this require some background.

This is not a solution of your problem, but it is an answer containing all my knowledge on this topic.

**Update** Now this problem seems to be fixed in current Ubuntu kernels. Realtek bluetooth should work out of the box.

Comment: I found a GitHub repository https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new, it is supposed to have all the new realtek drivers,  are there any precautions I should take before trying to install them?

Comment: That won't work. `rtlwifi-new` are only wireless drivers. There is `rtl8723au-bt` repo there (lwfinger). That's what I told about. But it does not work with new kernels. But you can try to contact Larry Finger, maybe he has some good news.

Comment: If it is useful to anyone else, I ended up installing ubuntu 16.04 over my broken system and Bluetooth is working fine now I guess it had something to do with me installing `blueman` on the broken system.

Comment: @Pilot6 Sorry for arguing and downvote You have right i have different chipset in my Lenovo i've deleted bad comment. My mistake :-( Have a nice day!

Comment: No problem. This happens. You have a correct solution for your chipset.You can revert the downvote though.